# ¿Cómo puedo usar el scroll del body para mover el contenido de un section fixed?

Tags: html, css, scroll

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 15%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.articles {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <section class="articles">
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí, quieres que con el scroll que tenga la etiqueta body se ejecute el scroll del section?

Comment: No entendí.... por favor explica mejor tu pregunta ! **es importante leer [ask]**

Comment: Tal ves te sirva este pluggin http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ Mantiene un elemento fixed en el area que le digas, pero tampoco entendi muy bien tu pregunta

Comment: sí, pero sin que sea visible el scroll del section.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que fueras mas especifico con tu pregunta para que puedas recibir una respuesta en especifico, pero, No se si a esto te refieres:

Tienes un `<section>` el cual le estableces un tamaño y una posición fija, lo único que se me ocurre es que le agregues un `scroll` a tu `section` esto mediante la propiedad `overflow:scroll` en la clase `.main` de tu código CSS.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 15%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll;
  
}

.articles {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Scroll</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="main">
  <section class="articles">
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
  </section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Respuesta 2: Mover el scroll de la pagina y el div usando JQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $("#scroll-main").scrollTop(scroll);
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 15%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll;
  
}

.articles {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#sec-2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Scroll</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section id="scroll-main" class="main">
  <section class="articles">
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, odio. Labore mollitia suscipit corporis, sint in accusantium, ipsam veniam veritatis, nesciunt fugit, inventore quaerat. Sit rem autem id dolor sint.</span></p>
    </article>
  </section>
</section>
<section id="sec-2">
 <h1>Seccion 2</h1>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Literalmente al mover el `scroll` de tu pagina se moverá el `scroll` de tu `section`

Comment: Podría servirme de ayuda en el que usas JQuery, hay alguna forma de mantener oculto el scroll del section main?.